# Jenkins: Subversion E175002: broken pipe

Tags: svn, jenkins

We got jenkins running with a external subversion server. We're behind a proxy server and all is configured correctly.
We use following versions :

- Jenkins : 1.656
- Jenkins-Subversion-Plugin : 2.5.7
- RedHat : 6.7

All run perferctly. Jenkins polled the Subversion, detects new commits and starts building the binaries. Since two days the polling is failing with following error:

```
Started on Apr 7, 2016 3:30:00 PM
Received SCM poll call on master for XXXX on Apr 7, 2016 3:30:00 PM
ERROR: Failed to check repository revision for XXXXX
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Broken pipe
svn: E175002: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/XXXXX'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.findStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:133)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineProperties(DAVUtil.java:242)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineInfo(DAVUtil.java:200)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:196)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:118)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:184)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:45)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:46)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:31)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doInfo(SVNWCClient.java:2523)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.parseSvnInfo(SubversionSCM.java:1220)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:78)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:26)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SubversionSCM.java:1416)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SCM.java:381)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:398)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1446)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1349)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:526)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:555)
    at hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.sendData(HTTPConnection.java:358)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:174)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:497)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:398)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:386)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:863)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doPropfind(DAVConnection.java:151)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getProperties(DAVUtil.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getResourceProperties(DAVUtil.java:76)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:100)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.findStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:122)
    ... 29 more
```

Does anybody also have this error? Do someone has any hints?

Any help should be very appreciated!

Comment: Does your job have any timeout? Otherwise it might be a network issue.

Comment: What @Martin said, also, test if you can manually checkout the repo from said jenkins server, it might actually not be jenkin's fault.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
No, there are no timeouts. All subversion commands (checkout, updated, ls) are working manually on the console with the jenkins users. That's why I think it's a Jenkins fault.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a proxy server / SVNkit problem and NOT a jenkins issue. We use locally the Cntlm (local proxy server) to connect to the company's proxy server with authentication. 
The console implementation of subversion (1.8.15) could handle it correctly with the Cntlm and SVNkit (which is used by Jenkins) doesn't. We're lookin for a workaround now with the company's IT people.